# Where does Gnome-To-Do stores it's file by default ?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

Does anyone knows where Gnome To-DO 3.28 store it's file ?

I have some ghost entries I can't remove

JF
[image]

Answer (score 8):

`gnome-todo` using `Evolution-Data-Server` as its storage back-end.

Its data are stored here:

```
~/.local/share/evolution/tasks
```

For example tasks list are in below file:

```
~/.local/share/evolution/tasks/system/tasks.ics
```

And its cache are stored here:

```
~/.cache/evolution/tasks
```

For more details about Evolution-Data-Server you can see [this](https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/3.10/data-storage.html.en) link.

Comment: Is there a way to access my tasks files in a way where I can actually see the contents of my tasks/to-dos on Ubuntu Disco Dingo? I want to make sure that I can back up those files properly but the link above is slightly vague in my opinion.

Comment: Data can be "imported" by copying this - but make sure all evolution server stuff is off and the todo app is also shutdown before you copy this/or rewrite the content of this file with the backup.